# unable to execute second application in composed-task-runner

Tags: java, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

In *spring-cloud-data-flow* shell, using c*omposed-task-runner* I have registered task as:

```
COMMAND: task create my-composed-task --definition "taskcsv && proccess"
```

and launched it by giving the required parameters as:

```
COMMAND: task launch my-composed-task --arguments "--composed-task-arguments=--path=D:\SpectraMD\patient.csv --path1=D:\SpectraMD\patient.csv
```

---

The `taskcsv` application ran and getting the result, but it is not ending and process application execution is not starting.

Comment: What database are you using for dataflow?

Comment: i am using sql server database

Comment: Try adding spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enabled=true as a property to your taskcsv app.